# How do I access the value of an HTML attribute from within CoffeeScript?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using the [summernote WYSIWYG editor](https://github.com/summernote/summernote-rails) along with SimpleForm.

So this form field:

```
<%= f.input :description, as: :summernote, placeholder: "Enter the description of the Job (e.g. 'Product Manager', 'Senior Ruby on Rails Developer')" %>
```

Generates the following HTML:

```
<textarea class="summernote optional" placeholder="Enter the description of the Job (e.g. 'Product Manager', 'Senior Ruby on Rails Developer')" data-provider="summernote" name="job[description]" id="job_description" style="display: none;"></textarea>
```

My SummerNote JS is executed as follows:

```
ready = ->
  $('[data-provider="summernote"]').each ->
    $(this).summernote(height: 300, toolbar: [['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear', 'fontname', 'fontsize', 'color']],
    ['font', ['strikethrough', 'superscript', 'subscript']], ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
    ['height', ['height']], ['insert', ['link', 'table', 'hr']]], placeholder: "Some placeholder copy")

$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', ready)
```

However, instead of the `Some placeholder copy`, I would like to pull the value that is specified in the form (i.e. the placeholder in the `<textarea>` field).

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this).attr "placeholder" # => the attribute value
```

It's basic jQuery. `this` is the textarea, and `.attr` is the jQuery method for reading/writing attribute values.

Comment: Perfect. Just what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: $(@), to match coffeescript style anstead of $(this)

Comment: @Exinferis Both are valid. Personally, I prefer to use `this` when I'm just referring to the object itself, and `@something` when referring to a property/method. Personal preference, sure, but I just think `@` looks odd by itself.